# Automating expanding trees and selecting checkboxes with Watir

Tags: ruby, checkbox, tree, watir, treenode

On a site, there is tree of nodes each associated with a checkbox. Those nodes then expand further into more checkboxes.
It looks similar to the following where `[]` represents a checkbox:

```
+ [] All
   + [] Fruit
   + [] Vegetables
```

and then expanded looks like this:

```
+ [] All
   - [] Fruit
        [] apple
   - [] Vegetables
        [] potato
        [] cucumber
```

There is then a button at the bottom of the screen that when pressed, gives you the price of the selected item.

I would like to write a script in Watir that does the following sequence of events:

```
1) Expands the node Fruit
2) Checks apple
3) Clicks the run button
4) Unchecks apple
5) Expands the node Vegetables
6) Checks potato
7) Clicks the run button
8) Unchecks potato
etc.. for all checkboxes and nodes
```

The tag for the apple checkbox looks like this:

```
<td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;" class="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn2CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn2CheckBox">
  <a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners','s0\\0\\189')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,'ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst2');" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst2">
  <font style="color:#FF0000;">apple</font>
</td>
```

Also, there are more nodes and items that will be added to the list later so I need the script to take that into account and go through the checkboxes in order without calling the specific id of the checkbox.

Any help in solving this problem would greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Update:
I came up with this code but I'd like to check for the last checkbox/node rather than hardcoding the for loops. I would also like to skip the checkboxes for nodes such as Fruit and Vegetable.

```
for n in (1...250)
  nodename = "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn" + n.to_s
  if ie.a(:id => nodename).exists?
    ie.link(:id, nodename).click
  end
end

ie.checkbox(:id => "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0CheckBox").clear

x = 1
for r in (1...250)
  checkboxname = "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn" + x.to_s + "CheckBox"
  nodename = "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn" + r.to_s

  if ie.a(:id => nodename).exists?
    x = x+1
    checkboxname = "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn" + x.to_s + "CheckBox"
  end

  if ie.checkbox(:id => checkboxname).exists?
    ie.checkbox(:id => checkboxname).set
    puts x
    ie.checkbox(:id => checkboxname).clear    
  end

  x = x + 1
end
```

Update: Here is more of the HTML. I actually have a hash set up as itemlist[[n,"item"]]=item, for example itemlist[[1,"item"]] = apple, that contains all the items I need to check the price on. Is there a way/would it be easier to see what the text is for each checkbox and then if itemlist.has_value?(checkbox_text) then check the box and assign that text to another hash? Basically, is there a way to check the boxes according to the text rather than the id of the checkbox?

```
<td><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data,0,document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0&#39;),&#39;-&#39;,document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0Nodes&#39;))"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=VNrMPzAA2o87avzl3UgiY8OisS6wrOp46COe6QqNhDQHCsy9zX-GTuzHAKk7njulOEns3hNoLIxbv9x1bv530iY_Shsd9ZHlF3pm4jNQi6u0zB6atkT0-K9kirzHDQNHYxlY8Q2&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="Collapse All (133,060)" style="border-width:0;" /></a></td><td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0CheckBox" /><a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners&#39;,&#39;s0&#39;)" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst0&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst0">All (133,060)</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table><div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0Nodes" style="display:block;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn1" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data,1,document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn1&#39;),&#39;t&#39;,document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn1Nodes&#39;))"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=D2aGfOHUjBmg4quHNr-mKkyc5juoGHdurzZqtoCU3qo2d457eKX9x0d2AS3LrrQULzPjC-9wC6hLlMxSFEvU6c9r8LmzgOeKWAi6ouEEkShvclKr0&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="Expand Ace Communications Group (0) &lt;img src=&#39;images/emergency.png&#39; alt=&#39;alert&#39; />" style="border-width:0;" /></a></td><td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn1CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn1CheckBox" /><a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners&#39;,&#39;s0\\0&#39;)" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst1&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst1">Fruit </a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn1Nodes" style="display:none;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=UZyrk961AUQRa1Dg14aXeNUU3AZcfF9PiakU0o_cO8MfbyWz58k50vr47p2ICDOjgAqF5UX_lVIhbj_y2BqKRU5Xwhic3cBNooK1CBd_cGP6COn60&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="" /></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=OftTkmJCEf6tGohvvdo_cbMxdnyHMLxScANk1YxbAhfKKp3_gvqoKFAIbK4gGFAKMagH78cKVSIS61WrK5fGcCaHWVUMPjXLTtDZIJISdqqtXFNI0&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="" /></td><td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn2CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn2CheckBox" /><a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners&#39;,&#39;s0\\0\\189&#39;)" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst2&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst2"><font style='color:#FF0000;'>apple</font>  </a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn3" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data,3,document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn3&#39;),&#39;t&#39;,document.getElementById(&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn3Nodes&#39;))"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=D2aGfOHUjBmg4quHNr-mKkyc5juoGHdurzZqtoCU3qo2d457eKX9x0d2AS3LrrQULzPjC-9wC6hLlMxSFEvU6c9r8LmzgOeKWAi6ouEEkShvclKr0&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="Expand Advantage (0)" style="border-width:0;" /></a></td><td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn3CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn3CheckBox" /><a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners&#39;,&#39;s0\\0&#39;)" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst3&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst3">Vegetable</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn3Nodes" style="display:none;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=UZyrk961AUQRa1Dg14aXeNUU3AZcfF9PiakU0o_cO8MfbyWz58k50vr47p2ICDOjgAqF5UX_lVIhbj_y2BqKRU5Xwhic3cBNooK1CBd_cGP6COn60&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="" /></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=yCq0KCcfK0lqwrgCU1UxuFJ0bJHMKjxD6S5t8OvIWXwTUBOYh1ZiQA4lD3ZpRuMNI-itrPIn3_rFzvZtrMP5g7PyyensT-Z003WldrY9pIgMSY5p0&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="" /></td><td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn4CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn4CheckBox" /><a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners&#39;,&#39;s0\\0\\119&#39;)" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst4&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst4">potato</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=UZyrk961AUQRa1Dg14aXeNUU3AZcfF9PiakU0o_cO8MfbyWz58k50vr47p2ICDOjgAqF5UX_lVIhbj_y2BqKRU5Xwhic3cBNooK1CBd_cGP6COn60&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="" /></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=yCq0KCcfK0lqwrgCU1UxuFJ0bJHMKjxD6S5t8OvIWXwTUBOYh1ZiQA4lD3ZpRuMNI-itrPIn3_rFzvZtrMP5g7PyyensT-Z003WldrY9pIgMSY5p0&amp;t=634963835619397560" alt="" /></td><td onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this)" onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn5CheckBox" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn5CheckBox" /><a class="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tvPartners&#39;,&#39;s0\\0\\1&#39;)" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartners_Data, this,&#39;ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst5&#39;);" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnerst5">cucumber</a></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried so far and where exactly you need help (ie please limit the scope rather than asking for an entire script to be written for you).

Comment: thanks for all of your help Justin Ko! :)

Comment: Can you supply more of the page's html - ideally a full tree like you originally described? The html sample so far only includes "apple", but we know nothing of the html for "fruit".

Comment: Yes i will include a larger sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding a loop for 1 to 250, you should be using collections to find all elements that match a particular criteria.

So instead of

```
for n in (1...250)
  nodename = "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn" + n.to_s
  if ie.a(:id => nodename).exists?
    ie.link(:id, nodename).click
  end
end
```

It should be

```
ie.links(:id => /ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn/).each do |link|
  link.click
end
```

Which could also be written as

```
ie.links(:id => /ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn/).each(&:click)
```

The key here is that `ie.links(:id => /ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn/)` returns all links that match the criteria or locator. A regular expression (regex) is used for checking the id as this allows partial matching of ids (ie any link id that contains the text `ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn`).

The same logic could be applied to the rest of your script (note that without a complete html sample, I am guessing a bit on what your code does):

```
#Expand the entire tree
ie.links(:id => /ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn/).each(&:click)

#Clear the first checkbox
ie.checkbox(:id => "ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn0CheckBox").clear

#Set and clear each checkbox
checkbox_id = /ContentPlaceHolder1_tvPartnersn/
ie.checkboxes(:id => checkbox_id).each do |checkbox|
  checkbox.set
  puts checkbox.id
  checkbox.clear
end
```

Depending on the html for the 'fruit' and 'vegetable' nodes, they may already get ignored by this code. Otherwise, you might need to change the checkbox_id or add a conditional check.

**Update**

If you want to set the checkbox based on the text, you can do:

```
ie.td(:text => 'apple').checkbox.set
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately all of the checkboxes are numbered in consecutive order and there is no way to differentiate between the node checkboxes and the other ones. Also, the "All" node is numbered 0 so that line for expanding the tree collapses the entire tree from the get-go. :P

Comment: There is likely a difference that differentiate them. If you update the question with the html for an entire tree, I could give you a better answer.

Comment: I actually have a hash set up as itemlist[[n,"item"]]=item, for example itemlist[[1,"item"]] = apple, that contains all the items I need to check the price on. Is there a way/would it be easier to see what the text is for each checkbox and then if itemlist.has_value?(checkbox_text) then check the box and assign that text to another hash? Basically, is there a way to check the boxes according to the text rather than the id of the checkbox? Thank you again!

Comment: Assuming you already know how to iterate through the hash, I have updated the answer to include a way to get the checkbox based on text.

Comment: Perfect! Lastly, the value in the hash may not always match the text of the checkbox 100% so I'd like to use RegExp to search for a partial match but how do I do a RegExp with variables? Something similar to ie.td(:text => /itemlist[[n,"item"]]/).checkbox.set while I am iterating through the hash

Comment: You can insert a variable into a regex using `#{variable}`. So you could do `ie.td(:text => /#{itemlist[[n,"item"]]}/).checkbox.set`

Comment: It is ridiculous how much you have helped me! Thank you so much again! I really appreciate it! I will definitely be checking out your Watir book when it comes out!